# How to build calculator with user input utilizing Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, calculator

I have been at this for hours and have not figured out the following issues with this basic calculator:

- The user input is invisible in the terminal. Why? What could be causing this?
- The program runs, but not as expected:

  - When the prompts for calculations() come up, the end calculations do not show... they are overlooked by the program. Any advice here? Maybe I have disorganized the code.
  - The 'q' for quitting the program executes, but not until it is pressed twice in the program. Why?

[basic calculator program sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NGyj.png)

I would sincerely appreciate any help with this as I am learning how to navigate Node.JS these days. Thanks so much!

```
const readline = require('readline');
const readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

// Variables
let operations = ['+', '-', '*', '/', 'q', 'add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide', 'quit'];
let index = null;
let operator = null;
let firstNumber = 0;
let secondNumber = 0;

//  function to expect answers and repeat the process recursively
let rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
});


// Console Dialogue
let username = readlineSync.question('Hello! What is your name? \n');

console.log('\nGreetings, ' + username + '!\n'
    + 'Welcome to the Regular Calculator Project.\n');

// run the program
console.log(operationQuestion(), exitProgram());


// function to Exit program
function exitProgram(){
  console.log('The program is complete. Exiting the program now...');
  process.exit(0);
}


// Function to navigate operations
function operationQuestion() {
  operator = readlineSync.question('Please type an operation to perform. Here are your options:\n'
      +'\nAddition ('+ operations[0]+')'
      +'\nSubtraction ('+ operations[1]+')'
      +'\nMultiplication ('+ operations[2]+')'
      +'\nDivision ('+ operations[3]+')\n'
      +'\nQuit the Program ('+ operations[4]+')\n\n'
  );

  // check if the user typed the right operator(s)
  if (!operations.includes(operator)) {
    console.log('That is not a valid operation. Please try again.\n');
    operationQuestion();
  }

  firstNumber = readlineSync.questionInt('Type the first number: ');
  secondNumber = readlineSync.questionInt('Type the second number: ');

  quitProgram = readlineSync.question(`Write 'q' again to confirm exit: `);

  // check if input is to quit, then user will proceed to exit the program
  if (readlineSync.question(quitProgram) == 'q') {
    return exitProgram()
  }

  // inner function to navigate basic calculations
  function calculations() {
    switch(operator) {
      case '+':
      case 'add' :
      case operations[0]:
      case operations[5]:
        console.log('The result of ' + firstNumber+operator+secondNumber+ ' = ' + (firstNumber+secondNumber) + '\n');
        break;

      case '-':
      case 'subtract':
      case operations[1]:
      case operations[6]:
        console.log('The result of ' + firstNumber+operator+secondNumber+ ' = ' + (firstNumber-secondNumber) + '\n');
        break;

      case '*':
      case 'multiply':
      case operations[2]:
      case operations[7]:
        console.log('The result of ' + firstNumber+operator+secondNumber+ ' = ' + (firstNumber*secondNumber) + '\n');
        break;

      case '/':
      case 'divide':
      case operations[3]:
      case operations[8]:
        console.log('The result of ' + firstNumber+operator+secondNumber+ ' = ' + ((firstNumber/secondNumber).toFixed(2)) + '\n');
        break;

      case 'q':
      case 'quit':
      case operations[4]:
      case operations[9]:
        console.log(quitProgram, exitProgram());
        break;

      default:
        console.log('Something went wrong: ');
        break;
    }
  }

  return operationQuestion()
}

rl.on("close", function() {
    console.log("\nExiting program now...");
    process.exit(0);
});
```